# How does Gnome clock/calendar applet get weather, sunset and sunrise time information?

Tags: gnome, api

How and where does this Gnome applet get weather information? Same question for sunrise and sunset times.

I suppose there is a web API it queries but which one and can I use it?

[image: gnome weather applet]

<sup>(sorry for the screenshot in french)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gnome-weather` uses [`libgweather`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libgweather/tree/libgweather) underneath which in turn uses several `GWeatherProviders` (defined in [`gweather-weather.h`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libgweather/tree/libgweather/gweather-weather.h)) to get weather information for your particular geo-location:

```
  * GWeatherProvider:
....
  * @GWEATHER_PROVIDER_METAR: METAR office, providing current conditions worldwide
  * @GWEATHER_PROVIDER_IWIN: US weather office, providing 7 days of forecast
  * @GWEATHER_PROVIDER_YAHOO: Yahoo Weather Service, removed in 3.27.1
  * @GWEATHER_PROVIDER_YR_NO: Yr.no service, worldwide but requires attribution
  * @GWEATHER_PROVIDER_OWM: OpenWeatherMap, worldwide and possibly more reliable, but requires attribution and is limited in the number of queries
....
```

You could look into the source code and see how they do it:
[`weather-metar.c`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libgweather/tree/libgweather/weather-metar.c),
[`weather-iwin.c`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libgweather/tree/libgweather/weather-iwin.c),
[`weather-yrno.c`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libgweather/tree/libgweather/weather-yrno.c),
[`weather-owm.c`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libgweather/tree/libgweather/weather-owm.c). See also [`weather.c`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libgweather/tree/libgweather/weather.c)

Sunrise and sunset times are computed in [`weather-sun.c`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libgweather/tree/libgweather/weather-sun.c)